# is there any image library can cut the white edge of a picture?

Tags: c++, image

I'd like to know if there are any image librarys can cut the white edge of a picture automatically,

for example:

- cut [The Wonderful Wizard of Oz.png](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_BVLRTqIDWuU/TIC-_woUeSI/AAAAAAAAACY/h0bQZk2fG4Q/s1600/The+Wonderful+Wizard+of+Oz.png)
- to [cutted.png](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_BVLRTqIDWuU/TIC-_vWUvcI/AAAAAAAAACQ/mCRnHlZ3jrM/s1600/cutted.png)

opensource would be very handy

Thanks advance for your help.

Best regards,

hb

Comment: It is called 'cropping'.  Quite do-able with your sample image.  It becomes a hard problem when you want to auto-crop a photo of you explaining your algorithm on a white-board.

Answer (score 2):

Any popular image library should be able to get the pixel value from an image. You can probably just determine which area is white and then cut that off using the library and save the result.

Check out [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/).

Comment: thanks a lot for all ,and I have found some examples here:http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#trim_color